# Items sent from Google Drive don't appear in Sent Items folder

Tags: gmail, google-drive

When I send a Google Drive file as attachment, the file does get sent, but the mail doesn't appear in Gmail's Sent Items folder.

Repro:

- Google Drive => Right-click on a document => Share... => `Email as attachment...`

  - I'm aware of `Email Collaborators...`, but that only works when everyone else uses Gmail.
- Complete To. Subject, Message, don't check "Send a copy to myself", hit Send
- Check with the recipient - he gets the mail with the attachment fine.
- **Expected:** Mail should appear in Sent Items
- **Actual:** Mail doesn't appear there, or anywhere else in Gmail.

Details:

- When sending/replying directly from Gmail (not Google Drive), mails do appear in Sent Items.
- I noticed that the recipient gets this mail with my name as `Jonathan Barner (Google Drive)`, rather than just `Jonathan Barner` - maybe that's related.
- I've disabled conversation display in Gmail.
- Using Gmail web interface, on Windows 8.1 and Chrome 34.0.1847.116 m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Drive is not an email client. It's not intended to be and thus, you will not see files being "sent". [This is intended.](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494886?hl=en)

> Google Drive lets you share your files and folders with exactly whom you want at whatever level of access you choose.
>
> - Collaborate in real time with colleagues, classmates, or friends
> - **Stop sending email attachments and start sharing**
> - Control who sees and edits your files with visibility options and access levels
> - Easily share your work with lots of people

This appears to be a feature and not a bug.

Comment: IMO, `Email as attachment...` is more like "half-hearted feature". If Google Drive wants to divert people from sending attachments, it should not offer this at all. Also, sharing would not work for my intended use - sending Resumes to less-technological people who may or may not have a Google account.

Comment: I don't think that they are attempting to divert so much as they are attempting to workaround the inherent limitations of email as a form of communication, attachment size and collaboration being two of the largest. If you ever find yourself emailing a document being worked on by two or more persons, then you know what can if a headache that can be. There should be a permanent link available when sharing that doesn't require the user to have a Google Account. Are you having a different experience?